# Is it possible to store and use RDLC file content to design report from database using c# .Net ReportViewer?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

For Example rather than using

```
ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
            reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "file.rdlc";
```

can I use something like this;

```
ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
            reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportDesign= XmlData;
```

Can someone help please?